# Jenkins Credentials

Tags: jenkins, credentials

I have restarted the container and every time I go get the password from the specified location I get an error when trying to log into jenkins.  I was in Jenkins at one point in time.

```
Getting Started
Unlock Jenkins

To ensure Jenkins is securely set up by the administrator, a 
password has been written to the log (not sure where to find it?) 
and this file on the server:

/var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

Please copy the password from either location and paste it below.
Administrator password



root@c3cc341d85c8:/etc/init.d# cat 
/var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
777446726bd54df08de588e089497068



Error
An error occurred
An error occurred during installation: ERROR:
```

I get this error over and over again.

Comment: When you give the `initialAdminPassword` in jenkins GUI what are you getting?

Comment: An error occurred during installation: ERROR:

Comment: How were you installing that? Can you send commands? For you installing java and running docker?